# <li> not taking up full width of the sidebar

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with an `<li>` not taking up full width of the sidebar, i.e. there is some space that is not coloured (with `background-color: red;`) on the left side. I know that the space comes from this line:

```
padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3em;
```

but I'm not sure how to achieve the same effect without using padding. I want the list items padded like that, but I also want my inner nested `<li>`s taking up full width of the sidebar.

Click 'Transactions' in the [demo](https://codepen.io/lbastos/pen/MWWVbgE) so you can see what I'm talking about.
So, one more time, for example 'New Transaction' should be coloured red and should take up the full width of the sidebar, from left to right edge.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li');

  function onListItemClick() {
    for (let listItem of listItems) {
      listItem.classList.remove('active');
      listItem.children[0].classList.remove('dot');
      if (listItem.children.length > 2) {
        listItem.children[2].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
    this.children[0].classList.add('dot');
    if (this.children.length > 2) {
      this.children[2].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
  listItems.forEach(function(listItem) {
    listItem.addEventListener('click', onListItemClick);
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10em 0 0 0;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25px 1fr;
  color: #959595;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3em;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li:hover,
.sidebar>nav>ul>li>ul>li:hover {
  color: #757575;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>ul>li {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  color: #959595;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0 0 0 2em;
}

.dot {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #33ad93;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

.active {
  color: black !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span></span>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span></span>
        <span>Transactions</span>
        <ul style="display:none;">
          <li>New Transaction</li>
          <li>View Transactions</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span></span>
        <span>Budgets</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: The CSS on line 17 of your demo is missing a semicolon. Adding that changes the appearance quite a bit. Can you fix that and see how that affects your question?

Comment: @jalynn2 That line wasn't supposed to be there, I'm sorry. The question still stands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer. I have changed css styles at two places where styles applied to nested list and nested items.

```
.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: -3em;
 width: 300px;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul > li {
 display: block;
 background-color: red;
 color: #959595;
 font-size: 14px;
 width: calc(100% - 5em);
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 0 0 0 5em;
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li');
  function onListItemClick() {
    for (let listItem of listItems) {
      listItem.classList.remove('active');
      listItem.children[0].classList.remove('dot');
      if (listItem.children.length > 2) {
        listItem.children[2].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
    this.children[0].classList.add('dot');
    if (this.children.length > 2) {
      this.children[2].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
  listItems.forEach(function(listItem) {
    listItem.addEventListener('click', onListItemClick);
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10em 0 0 0;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li {
    background-color: red
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25px 1fr;
    color: #959595;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3em;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li:hover, .sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover {
    color: #757575;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: -3em;
    width: 300px;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    color: #959595;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 0 0 5em;
}

.dot {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #33ad93;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}

.active {
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span></span>
                <span>Dashboard</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span></span>
                <span>Transactions</span>
                <ul style="display:none;">
                    <li>New Transaction</li>
                    <li>View Transactions</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span></span>
                <span>Budgets</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```